# Upload file to Jersey web services with spring MultipartFile

Tags: java, spring, rest, jersey, multipartform-data

I have a 3 step process to upload a file on a server:

1. Using EXT.JS form, I upload a file to a controler.
2. In the controler, the method gets the MultipartFile, builds a rest call using rest template and send it to the server.
3. On the server, the specified method should receive the multipart data and process the file.

Here is the method at the step 2 that get the file from the UI side (EXT.JS):

```
@RequestMapping("/customerUploadFile/upload")
@ResponseBody
public JsonResponse uploadFile(CustomerUploadBean bean,
        @RequestParam("filePath") MultipartFile filePath) throws IOException {



    long fileSize = filePath.getSize();

    HttpEntity<CustomerUploadBean> httpEntity = getHttpEntity(bean);
    byte[] byteArr = filePath.getBytes();

    MultiValueMap<String, Object> parameters = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();

    parameters.add("userId", httpEntity.getHeaders().get("userId"));
    parameters.add("file", byteArr);

    // to set content type of header
    org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders headers = new org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    ResponseEntity<JsonResponse> jsonResponse = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST,
            new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(parameters, headers),
            new ParameterizedTypeReference<JsonResponse>() {
            });

    JsonResponse response = jsonResponse.getBody();
    if (jsonResponse.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
        response.setSuccess(true);

    } else {
        response.setSuccess(false);
    }
    return response;
}
```

I've verified, the filePath object have the file and contains information about the file.

At the step 3, here is the method in the controller on the server that awaits for the file to process it:

```
public Response importUserProfileCSV(
        @ApiParam(value = "Service Name", required = true) @PathParam("service") String service,
        @ApiParam(value = "CSV file to upload.", required = true) @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @ApiParam(value = "CSV file detail", required = true) @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

    return delegate.importUserProfileCSV(uploadedInputStream, fileDetail,
            service, "user");

}
```

The problem here is that at the step 3, in the method right above, the ***fileDetail*** object contains only null values... How can I adapt the method of step 2 (spring framework) to the method of step 3 (jersey).

Comment: I guess Jersey doesn't really support injecting same parameter multiple times (given as you seem to have non-null InputStream in your example, or at least ths is what I can infer). Try using `FormDataBodyPart` instead. That way you can both query file content disposition and access InputStream via `part.getValueAs(InputStream.class)`.

Comment: Oh, and. Your Spring example has `filePath` parameter name, while Jersey example has `file`. Does it have to do with anything?

Comment: Okay I'll try the solution ***FormDataBodyPart*** in the spring method I'm adding a parameter named ***file*** before making the request to the jersey part

Comment: Ah, I see now. I thought those were processing same request. I think you will not have content disposition in this case anyway, because all that you are sending is bytearray. Have you tried sending a `MultipartFile` as a whole thing?

Comment: When I'm passing the MultipartFile directly, I have an ***WriteJson Exception*** and the request cannot be send

Comment: _"the fileDetail object contains only null values"_ - All the values are part of the `Content-Disposition` header that you set for that specific body part. You have not set any headers for your request. You need to use an `HttpEntity` in order to set headers for individual parts. So instead of `parameters.add("file", byteArray)`, you would use `parameters.add("file", httpEntity)`